# What is the structure of a window in tornadofx?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

So in javafx, windows of UI's are made like this: nodes inside scenes inside a stage. Sometimes nodes get nested inside other nodes.
[the structure of a javafx ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzYps.png)
I know that in tornadofx, there are still nodes. They still nest inside each other. HBox, datagrid, etc.
But in tornadofx, we use fragments and views. They are "UI elements", according to the manual. What are these? Are they nodes? Stages?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A View or Fragment, or any UIComponent sub type, is a container for a root Node, which can be attached to anything a Node normally can be attached to. Think of View/Fragment as a Controller for the UI logic of a certain root node and it's children. With the builder syntax, you can "add" a View or Fragment to a Node. What happens under the covers is quite simply that the `root` node of the View is attached to the `children` list of the Node you add it to.

Comment: Thank you! Adding a View/Fragment to a Node means making that View/Fragment display when the node is displayed, right? And that's different fro putting a Node in a View/Fragment.

Comment: That's basically correct, yes. There is absolutely no magic - the root Node is just added to the children list. Nothing more, nothing less :)